# Third power of the trace and trace of the third power

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u \in W^{1,3}(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ a smooth and bounded domain of $\mathbb R^n$, and $T$ denote the trace operator.

Using standard results and the usual notations, we have on the one hand
$$ x := \|T(\phi^3)\|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)}\leq C \|\phi^3\|_{W^{1,1}(\Omega)} \leq C \left(\|\phi^3\|_{L^1(\Omega)} + \|\phi^2 \, D\phi\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\right),$$
and on the other 
$$ y := \|T(\phi)\|_{L^3(\partial \Omega)}^3 \leq C \|\phi\|_{W^{1,3}(\Omega)}^3 \leq C (\|\phi^3\|_{L^1(\Omega)} + \||D\phi|^3\|_{L^1(\Omega)}).$$
I have two questions about this. First, can one show that $x = y$? If not, is it possible to prove that
$$ C_1\,y \leq x \leq C_2 \, y?$$
The second inequality is true because, using Holder inequality with $p = 3/2, q = 3$ and Young inequality, 
$$\|\phi^2 \, D\phi\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq C \, \|\phi^3\|_{L^1(\Omega)}^{2/3} \||D\phi|^3\|_{L^1(\Omega)}^{1/3} \leq C(\|\phi^3\|_{L^1(\Omega)} +  \||D\phi|^3\|_{L^1(\Omega)}). $$
The first one, however, seems less obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$, the trace operator coincides with restriction to $\partial \Omega$ and so $T(\phi)^3 = T(\phi^3)$. In consequence, $$ \|T(\phi^3)\|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)} = \|T(\phi)^3\|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)} = \|T(\phi)\|^3_{L^3(\partial\Omega)}. $$

As you observed, for general $\phi \in W^{1,3}(\Omega)$ we have $\phi^3 \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and so both functions have meaningful traces (respectively in $L^3$ and $L^1$). For sufficiently regular domain $\Omega$ there exists an approximating sequence $\phi_k \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $\phi_k \to \phi$ in $W^{1,3}(\Omega)$. Then one can check that also $\phi_k^3 \to \phi^3$ in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$. Since $\|T(\phi_k^3)\|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)} = \|T(\phi_k)\|^3_{L^3(\partial\Omega)}$ for all $k$ and $T$ is continuous (in both settings), the same equality holds also for $\phi$.